# Is it possible to export data in PDF from handsontable data grid

Tags: jquery, html, handsontable

I am looking forward to use "handsontable" data grid in new project for quotation management. As I have gone through its document But I am unable to find that data of that grid can be export in pdf. So how can export that data-grid data to pdf with same format.

Answer (score 0):

It only allow to export as csv and also in only pro version after it you can use third party js for converting your csv to pdf or best way is to do it at server level

Comment: But the problem is the merge cells and formatting will be lost if we export to csv and than convert that csv to pdf. I need the same format.

Comment: there is hack for it you can open it as excel in popup window and get html of that window as such you will get your html page with all your format :) but i never used this trick.. Go ahead and try it and if you find it worthy plz upvote me

Comment: I tried that but its not working I am getting html content in xls file not the output. Correct me If I am worng.

Comment: yes because you opened popup as content type: xls let me try another options